# How i can correct this error of pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

please solve the problem of getting error in pubspec.yaml file when i put image in assets folder

[image]

Comment: At least properly write your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an indention error.
Pubspec file Strictly follows the indention rule.

So try to remove one extra Space before assets

Comment: where i can remove extra space?

Comment: line 48  before     ^assets :

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is not correct in your code.
this is the correct format :

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/bg.png
```

detailed :

```
flutter:
[2 spaces]assets:
[4 spaces]-[1 space]assets/bg.png
```

make sure to run `flutter pub get` after changes!

Answer (score 0):

It is a space error

Try to write it like this

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/image/abc.png
    - assets/image/abc.jpeg
```